# TypeORM @Entity SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

I'm trying to use TypeORM in Javascript node app but when I created my first Entity and tried to run the app I got Invalid or unexpected token

```
@Entity({ name: "application_users" })
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:115:18)
at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:289:14)
```

Entity:

```js
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity({ name: "application_users" })
export class User {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: String;

  @Column()
  biography: String;

  @Column()
  country: String;

  @Column()
  email: String;

  @Column()
  image: String;
}
```

Data Source:

```js
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "postgres",
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  logging: true,
  synchronize: true,
  entities: [User],
});

AppDataSource.initialize()
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to DB"))
  .catch((err) => console.error("Failed connecting to DB", err));
```

Comment: Decorators are only available when using TypeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due using TypeScript syntax in JavaScript files.